# Showing a binary operation is well defined

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G=\{x\in\mathbb{R}~|~0\le x<1\}$ and define $\star$ as follows

$$x\star y=x+y-[x+y]$$

I want to show this is a well defined operation.  I think it is this easy;

If $x=x', y=y'$, then

$$x\star y = x+y-[x+y]=x'+y'-[x'+y']=x'\star y'$$

Is this accurate?

Comment: You need to show the result of the operation lands in $G$. In other words, you have to show $x,y \in G \implies x*y \in G$.

Comment: Also, no need for $x',y'$ -- just use $x,y$.

Comment: Why do some proof of the well-defined property use the "prime" argument that I used and some do not?

Comment: You would have to give an example to understand what you're referring to.

Comment: This operation is bascially defining the fractional part of a number, so it's well defined, right?  So is it that easy?

Comment: @quasi, [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Modulo_Addition_is_Well-Defined) is an example

Comment: Perhaps you mean that to show a function definition is well defined, you need to show $a=b \implies f(a) = f(b)$. But in this case, it's clear that the operation is well defined as a function. The only thing left to show is the result of the operation lands back in $G$.

Comment: Right, in that link, you have a _possible_ function, and to show it's actually a function (i.e., is well defined), you have to show that given any input, any two ways of computing the result yield the same output.

Comment: But in this case, you have an operation which is defined as a sum of known functions, hence is a function. The only question is whether it qualifies as an operation on $G$ (i.e., are the outputs always in $G$?).

Comment: I see.  That makes total sense now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have:

$$\lfloor x \rfloor \le x \lt \lfloor x \rfloor + 1$$

so that:

$$0 \le x-\lfloor x \rfloor\lt 1$$

So your function is well defined
 $$x\star y:G\to G$$